# HTML CSS stop watch

Tags: html, css, alignment, erb

I was trying to style and align the header with
(i) stop watch to the right along with "Login" link,
(ii) the logo to the left along with a link to "Home" and
(iii) the content with logo and form would be in the center in body part.
Tried to float and align but it just messed up, could not find what I am making error new bee here, any help will be appreciated thank you.

**update: Have been trying to debug, it looks like

- html code for header messes up the layout of the header and
- while refreshing it looks like something is overlapping the style.
- The header format look to be overlapped with some styling

  but could not find the exact error and any help is appreciated. Thank You**

**HTML CODE for header**

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container">
      <%= link_to image_tag("images.jpeg", alt: "Logo"),
                id: "logo" %>
        <nav>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left">
            <li><%= link_to "Home",    root_path %></li>
          
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
            <li><%= link_to "Log in", users_path %></li>
          </ul>
    
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
            <li> <!-- Lets make a simple stopwatch using CSS3 -->
                <!-- Time for the markup -->
                <!-- The core logic is a simple div containing numbers being moved
                using keyframe animations. The numbers have space between them so that they
                can be aligned vertically easily by reducing the container width. Lets
                wrap up the 'numbers' in a cell to display only 1 digit-->
    
                <!-- We will replicate the digits now -->
                <div class="container">
                  <!-- time to add the controls -->
                  <input id="start" name="controls" type="radio" />
                  <input id="stop" name="controls" type="radio" />
                  <input id="reset" name="controls" type="radio" />
                  <div class="timer">
                    <div class="cell">
                      <div class="numbers tenhour moveten">0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell">
                      <div class="numbers hour moveten">0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell divider"><div class="numbers">:</div></div>
                    <div class="cell">
                      <div class="numbers tenminute movesix">0 1 2 3 4 5 6</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell">
                      <div class="numbers minute moveten">0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell divider"><div class="numbers">:</div></div>
                    <div class="cell">
                      <div class="numbers tensecond movesix">0 1 2 3 4 5 6</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell">
                      <div class="numbers second moveten">0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell divider"><div class="numbers">:</div></div>
                    <div class="cell">
                      <div class="numbers milisecond moveten">0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell">
                      <div class="numbers tenmilisecond moveten">0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell">
                      <div class="numbers hundredmilisecond moveten">0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9</div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Lables for the controls -->
                    <div id="timer_controls">
                      <label for="start">Start</label>
                      <label for="stop">Stop</label>
                      <label for="reset">Reset</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
    
                  <!-- Lets load up prefixfree first -->
                  <script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/prefixfree.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                      </nav>
                  </header> 
                  </li>'
```

**CSS CODE**

```
/* mixins, variables, etc. */

$gray-medium-light: #eaeaea;

@mixin box_sizing {
  -moz-boz-sizing:      border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:   border-box;
  box-sizing:           border-box;
}

/* universal */

html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
  background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #167EA8), color-stop(1, #0E0754) );
  background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #167EA8 5%, #0E0754 100% );
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#167EA8', endColorstr='#0E0754');
  background-color:#167EA8; 
  color:#FFFBFA; 
  font-size: 12px; 
  font-weight: bold;
}

section {
  overflow: auto;
}

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
  h1 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}

/* header */

#logo small{
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2px;
  font-size: 1.0em;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  &:hover {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}

* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}


.container {
  padding: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.timer {
  padding: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(top, #222, #444);
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 7px solid #efefef;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  
  box-shadow: 
    inset 0 -2px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), 
    0 5px 20px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.cell {
  /*Should only display 1 digit. Hence height = line height of .numbers
  and width = width of .numbers*/
  width: 0.60em;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.numbers {
  width: 0.6em;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-family: digital, arial, verdana;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  
  /*Glow to the text*/
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

/*Styles for the controls*/
#timer_controls {
  margin-top: -5px;
}
#timer_controls label {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: #efefef;
  font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
  font-size: 11px;
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}
input[name="controls"] {display: none;}

/*Control code*/
#stop:checked~.timer .numbers {animation-play-state: paused;}
#start:checked~.timer .numbers {animation-play-state: running;}
#reset:checked~.timer .numbers {animation: none;}

.moveten {
  /*The digits move but dont look good. We will use steps now
  10 digits = 10 steps. You can now see the digits swapping instead of 
  moving pixel-by-pixel*/
  animation: moveten 1s steps(10, end) infinite;
  /*By default animation should be paused*/
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
.movesix {
  animation: movesix 1s steps(6, end) infinite;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

/*Now we need to sync the animation speed with time speed*/
/*One second per digit. 10 digits. Hence 10s*/
.second {animation-duration: 10s;}
.tensecond {animation-duration: 60s;} /*60 times .second*/

.milisecond {animation-duration: 1s;} /*1/10th of .second*/
.tenmilisecond {animation-duration: 0.1s;}
.hundredmilisecond {animation-duration: 0.01s;}

.minute {animation-duration: 600s;} /*60 times .second*/
.tenminute {animation-duration: 3600s;} /*60 times .minute*/

.hour {animation-duration: 36000s;} /*60 times .minute*/
.tenhour {animation-duration: 360000s;} /*10 times .hour*/

/*The stopwatch looks good now. Lets add some styles*/

/*Lets animate the digit now - the main part of this tutorial*/
/*We are using prefixfree, so no need of vendor prefixes*/
/*The logic of the animation is to alter the 'top' value of the absolutely
positioned .numbers*/
/*Minutes and Seconds should be limited to only '60' and not '100'
Hence we need to create 2 animations. One with 10 steps and 10 digits and
the other one with 6 steps and 6 digits*/
@keyframes moveten {
  0% {top: 0;}
  100% {top: -400px;} 
  /*height = 40. digits = 10. hence -400 to move it completely to the top*/
}

@keyframes movesix {
  0% {top: 0;}
  100% {top: -240px;} 
  /*height = 40. digits = 6. hence -240 to move it completely to the top*/
}


/*Lets use a better font for the numbers*/
@font-face {
  font-family: 'digital';
  src: url('http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/fonts/DS-DIGI.TTF');
  }
```

**Body part, Home Page**

```
<% provide(:title, "Home") %>
<div class="center jumbotron">
  <h1><%= link_to image_tag("logoo.jpg", alt: "Logo") %></h1>
  <h2>
    Interviewer Name <%= text_field_tag('input_second', 'First Middle Last Name', class: 'input-large') %>
  </h2>
  <h2>
    Interviewee Name <%= text_field_tag('input_second', 'First Middle last Name', class: 'input-large') %>
  </h2>
  <h2>
    Date <%= text_field_tag('input_second', 'mm/dd/yyyy', class: 'input-large') %>
  </h2>
  <%= link_to "Begin Interview Now", about_path, class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
 </div>
```

Comment: You lost me completely at the top when you were explaining what you want to do.

Comment: @user3334690 I am trying to style and align the header,put VMware logo and Home to left top and stopwatch and Login to right and body will be center body.

Comment: I have added a screen shot of previous page, which might make it clear, wanted to add stop watch in the header top right.

Comment: You would do well to try clarifying that in the question a bit... The current stream of consciousness is a bit hard to follow. Also, it appears to me that the code you've provided is from an erb, but the question is only tagged for css and html. I would agree that the question is only really about the css, with html for structure. You should consider showing the generated html instead of the erb in your question.  You might also consider including a jsfiddle, or using the code-snippet, after which you could remove the pictures. This would clean up your question, such that people might read it.

Comment: @user3334690 thank you for the information, does it make better sense now?

Comment: I got -2, why is that and what should i do to avoid it?

Comment: The numbers and removal of the pictures helps a bit. However, by putting all the code together in one code block you've made it harder to read and understand.  You might consider looking at meta overflow for some discussions of what makes a good question.

Comment: @user3731311 You are likely receiving some downvotes because your question is not very clear and you have posted a large amount of code instead of a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please read up on that post and the rest of the help center to help you improve your posts.

Comment: @JackieChiles thank you, I have tried my best to make it minimal, complete and verifiable. Will keep it in my now appreciate your directions. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: @JackieChiles just curious, do we not get help after we get downvotes?

Comment: @user3731311 That is not the case. Often you can still get answers after receiving downvotes. There is a lot of content to work through in your question, so you may just have to wait for an answer, or try to further improve the question based on the help documentation.

Comment: @JackieChiles I cannot even ask a question now and have not got any help and still trying to solve the problem, well I tried to improve my questions.